# How do I force close a port being used by an independent service?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, port

For example, if I have my minecraft server running on port 25565, I want to have a python script close the port so that all connections will be dropped and no further connections will be made without having to shutdown the service. 
I have tried binding a new socket to the same port number and then closing the socket, but it does not have any effect on the server.

I am working in Python 3.3.

Comment: This is not really a problem that python can solve by itself. Your OS may provide such functionality, but you didn't mention which one you're using

Answer (score 0):

Use a firewall for example?
On linux there is the iptables. It's easy to use and powerful.